# What are the options for remote users accessing a second exchange server?

Tags: email, exchange, outlook

We have a number of users working for and located at an external company. They access the local network via a VPN and have local AD accounts with corresponding exchange accounts.

I want them to be able to use their local email addresses and access shared folders on the exchange server however, they log into their primary domain first and access their own exchange server via outlook. I understand this means they cannot access a second exchange server.

The options as I understand them are so:
1. Outlook web access. Unfortunately this is locked down to a subset of privileged users with secure token ids.
2. Use a different client via IMAP. This is currently not available so I would have to fight with the exchange admins to get this enabled.
3. Run a virtual machine with a separate copy of outlook. Not really that nice.

Any other options available to me?

Comment: Just to clarify, do the users need to run the two instances of outlook simoultanously? If not, maybe just a second profile and selection at startup will do the trick (but I already think, you're asking about running the instances at the same time, dont you? ;-) )

Answer (score 1):

You've pretty much got it there, unfortunately. There's no really good solution for what you're trying to do. You might try experimenting with running Outlook as different user with "RunAs" simultaneously with the user's normal session and see how it acts. You're definitely into "unsupported" territory with that, but it just might work.

Comment: Interesting. I'll get the guys to give this a try, thanks

Answer (score 1):

Extra Outlook is a freeware program that says it is designed to run multiple copies of Outlook at the same time.  I cannot vouch for its claims, but...

http://www.nirmaltv.com/2009/01/02/run-multiple-instances-of-outlook-with-extra-outlook/

Answer (score 0):

You could run a Virtual PC instance with Outlook and use the virtual instance to connect to your domain.  This of course has licensing consequences if you are one who sticklers for that sort of thing, and also will use two IP addresses on the external network.

Comment: Yeah, this was my least favourite option on the least but these guys are all developers so the licensing issue is not such a problem.

Answer (score 0):

Just had a brainwave. Being developers they are able to use remote desktop to access a number of development servers. If we installed outlook on a development server, they could all use outlook on this.

Comment: Maybe on top of that run the Outlook as a remote app, to have the seamless integration in the "normal" desktop.